# Programatically access chrome and firefox passwords on mac/win?

Tags: c#, objective-c, google-chrome, firefox

Is there a way to programatically access chrome and firefox passwords on mac and/or windows? I have done some searching for the past few days and have come up empty handed.

I find password managers to be annoying or too complex. I am looking for something simple that would just sync logins between the two browsers. I have experience with both C# and objective-c and would be interested in creating something for at least personal use, possibly open source it if others find it useful.

Where are the logins stored?

What are the obstacles in getting this to work?

Are there any code snippets to do this already out there?

I am of course making som assumptions, thanks for any help feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I did a lot of searching to get to the files, pretty obvious once I thought about it a bit more.

In newer versions of chrome the passwords are stored in an sqlite database which is called login data. Passwords are encrypted but can be decrypted (this would be one of the problems in making the application). You will find the file under the following locations.

Mac
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default

Win 7
C:\Users\\Appdata\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

In the same way you will find the passwords for Firefox. Login information is stored in the key3.db and signons.sqlite files. These files are found in the [profile folder](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Profiles#How_to_find_your_profile).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, here is an example from the commandline :

```
cp ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Login\ Data db  && sqlite3 db 'select * from logins' && rm db
```

The `cp` is done to make the command work even if Chrome is running and has locked the database, but it is not needed if you know this will run without chrome running.